# How to use gcloud compute scp over a proxy network?

Tags: proxy, gcloud, scp

I want to use gcloud compute scp over an authentication proxy network. I tried setting the proxy in gcloud command line sdk using

[gcloud proxy settings](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings)

Thereafter, I tried

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse nakumgaurav25@instance-2:~/myData ~/Desktop
```

But it doesn't work. The error shown is

ssh: connect to host 35.230.136.59 port 22: Connection timed out.

Note that the same command works when I disable the proxy settings and connect my PC to a non-proxy network.

Answer (score 0):

are you still getting the connection refused message ? I need a little be more info to help you out; **(1)** which type of proxy are you using? **(2)** the remote machine (VM) is a linux OS? because is not possible use `gcloud compute scp` from a [Windows VM](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp). assuming the remote machine is using Linux OS, have you try to set a variable on your local host `export http_proxy=server-ip:port` then set again the proxy.